# Build hash from collection of ActiveRecord Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to build a hash from a Model.

This is the type of hash I want to build.

```
{"United Sates" => "us", "United Kingdom" => "uk" .....}
```

I have tried so many ways now I'm just going around in circles.

Here are just some of my poor attempts.

```
select = Array.new
countries.each do |country|
  # select.push({country.name => country.code })
  # select[country.name][country.code]
end

h = {}

countries.each do |c|
  # h[] = {c.name => c.code}
  # h[] ||= {} 
  # h[][:name] = c.name
  # h[][:code] = c.code 
  #h[r.grouping_id][:name] = r.name
  # h[r.grouping_id][:description] = r.description
end
```

Please can some advise.

Thank You

Comment: Some code or even show us what you've tried could help.

Comment: Use the Force... - i mean just use `pluck` and `to_h`   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836177/1536309

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here are some one-liner alternatives:

```
# Ruby 2.1+
name_to_code = countries.map{ |c| [c.name,c.code] }.to_h

# Ruby 1.8.7+
name_to_code = Hash[ countries.map{ |c| [c.name,c.code] } ]

# Ruby 1.8.6+
name_to_code = Hash[ *countries.map{ |c| [c.name,c.code] }.flatten ]

# Ruby 1.9+
name_to_code = {}.tap{ |h| countries.each{ |c| h[c.name] = c.code } }

# Ruby 1.9+
name_to_code = countries.to_a.each_with_object({}){ |c,h| h[c.name] = c.code }
```

Courtesy of @Addicted's comment below:

```
# Ruby 1.8+
name_to_code = countries.inject({}){ |r,c| r.merge c.name=>c.code }
```

Comment: Fantastic.  I tried map with no success also but great list. TY

Comment: @Lee If the `map` options didn't work, please provide details. For example, what does `p countries.class` show?

Comment: A more compact way to do the same thing ---                           countries.inject({}) do |result, country|
    result.merge(country.name => visitor.code)
end

Answer (score 21):

With Rails 4 you could simply do:

```
country_codes = Hash[Country.pluck(:name, :code)]
```

Which I think is optimal because you don't have to load a bunch of country objects and iterate through them

The pluck method on Rails 3 does not allow more than one attribute, but you could do something like:

```
 country_codes = Hash[Country.connection.select_rows(Country.select('name, code').to_sql)]
```

Answer (score 11):

My favorite Answer these days is to use `pluck` and `to_h`

```
countries.pluck(:name, :code).to_h
# => {"United Sates" => "us", "United Kingdom" => "uk" .....}
```

to reverse them and have the code first

```
countries.pluck(:code, :name).to_h
# => {"us" => "United Sates", "uk" => "United Kingdom" .....}
```

Answer (score 8):

Define the countries hash then fill it from your records.

```
countries_hash = {}
countries.each do |c|
  countries_hash[c.name] = c.code
end
```

Comment: Thank you Douglas. Building the block worked perfect thank you. The inject cave me errors. But ill keep playing. thank you.

Comment: Removed the inject example, my inject-fu is obviously weak this evening.

Comment: I think you want this to strengthen your inject-fu: `countries_hash = countries.inject({ }){ |hsh, c| hsh[c.name] = c.code; hsh }`; [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) passes the return value of the block to the next round. There's also the [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) variant of `inject` that doesn't suffer this problem (but note the different argument order): `countries_hash = countries.each_with_object({ }){ |c, hsh| hsh[c.name] = c.code }`.

Comment: A more compact way to do the same thing ---                           countries.inject({}) do |result, country|
    result.merge(country.name => visitor.code)
end