# ActiveRecord mass update where modify data from column in terms of itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord

I'm having trouble updating a phone column (there's a lot of records, so it needs to be done efficiently) where the phone value is changed according to a regex. I'm trying to make something like the following work:

```
Address.where("phone IS NOT NULL").update_all(:phone, phone.gsub(/[^\w|+]/, ""))
```

or preferably using sql:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE addresses SET phone=#{phone.gsub(/[^\w|+]/, "")} WHERE phone IS NOT NULL")
```

Any ideas how to do this efficiently? My previous attempt was wayyy too slow given the scale of records:

```
Address.where("phone IS NOT NULL").find_each do |address|
  address.phone = address.phone.gsub(/[^\w|+]/, "")
  address.save
end
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: @hwnd letters are fine, like "ext"

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

As you might have noted update_all is the best way to do this. The main problem is that update_all generates the SQL and hits the DB only once with it to get the final results. So if you need phones (an intermediary result), you just can't use this method. From the doc:

> This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it
>   straight to the database.

There is no way to accomplish that in a one-way step. My solution would be to work with 1 query and one mass update via SQL.

```
CONN = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

id_phones = Address.where("phone is NOT NULL").map {|address| address.id => address.phone.gsub(/[^\w|+]/, '')}

id_phones.each {|id, phone| CONN.execute "UPDATE addresses SET phone='#{phone}' WHERE id='#{id}' " }
```

Just like update_all, this solution skips validations and callbacks. But I think you are aware of that.

Comment: That's invalid syntax btw, you'd want something like `id_phones = Address.where("phone is NOT NULL").map {|address| [address.id, address.phone.gsub(/[^\w|+]/, '')] }.to_h` for Ruby 2.1+. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519380/build-hash-from-collection-of-activerecord-models